# SSL Certificate Verification error when connecting to external database in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

New to python and jupyter notebook. I'm trying to import some sample datasets in the `seaborn` package:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
```

**Output**

> SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py
>   in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1318
>   try:
>   -> 1319                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,    1320
>   encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

there are several lines in the `traceback` - I've only posted the first chunk above for brevity.

From what I've read so far, this happens because the `load_dataset` function is trying to load data from the seaborn github page and the internet/security settings are not allowing the connection to go through. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: MacOS Mojave. `certifi` is already updated to the latest version. Might've found a way to make it work using the `Install Certificate` command - will update after I restart.

Comment: Yup..It should work now. In mac, we have to install the certs from "Install Certificates.command" file